# How to place the upper rectangular text in the middle of the big rectangular border

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

[image]

I knew of the existence of a form html element with its writing in the upper left corner, but nothing more. Is it that I need to translate on X and Y axis according to the parenting div.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: I put the lower 2 descriptions inside the bordering div, added flexbox and padding to them. Now I need to style the upper middle, on border description, on the parent border, and I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) element is used to group content within a web form.

The [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) element represents a caption for the `<fieldset>`.

```css
legend {
    margin: auto;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Drawing Centric</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: To center, add to legend: `margin:auto`